# Test suite failed to run , Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I have a problem while running "npm run test" in my angular App, the console prints this message "Test suite failed to run , Jest encountered an unexpected token", and I don't know why.

This is the result of my tests in console :

```
Test Suites: 5 failed, 7 passed, 12 total
Tests:       24 passed, 24 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        28.73s
```

And this is my set-up :

babel.config.js :

```
 module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};
```

package.json:

```
"jest": {
"preset": "jest-preset-angular",
"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setupJest.ts",
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
  "./node_modules/",
  "./src/test.ts"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the compilerOptions in your tsconfig.spec.json:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```